# Sending express response with data from 2 different mongoose queries

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I need to query 2 different collections and send it in the express response. I have a very vague idea of what is needed to do so. I tried to contact the query documents to an empty array and send that new array as the response. But I receive an empty array as a response.

This is my route.

```
  site.route('/campus/development')
    .get(function(req, res) {
        var devPosts = [];

        development.find().exec(function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error : ' + err);
            } else {
                if (docs != null) {
                    devPosts = devPosts.concat(docs);
                    console.log(docs);
                } else {
                    console.log('No posts found');
                }
            }
        });

        jobs.find().exec(function(err, jobs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('Error : ' + err);
            } else {
                if (jobs != null) {
                    devPosts = devPosts.concat(jobs);
                    console.log(jobs);
                } else {
                    console.log('No jobs');
                }
            }
        });

        res.send(devPosts);
    });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the async operation of the requests to the database. There are a variety of solutions to this but basically distill down to two types: callbacks or promises.

A callback solution might look like:

```
  site.route('/campus/development')
    .get(function(req, res) {
      development.find().exec(function(err, devDocs) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error : ' + err);
        } else {
          if (devDocs != null) {
            console.log(devDocs);

            jobs.find().exec(function(err, jobs) {
              if (err) {
                console.log('Error : ' + err);
              } else {
                if (jobs != null) {
                  console.log(jobs);

                  res.send([devDocs, jobs]);
                } else {
                  console.log('No jobs');
                }
              }
            });
          } else {
            console.log('No posts found');
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

But this introduces a couple of interesting issues: one is the phenomenon known as callback hell and the other is that you should be responding with the errors which means you would need to have a response call for each error (albeit this is a very simplistic approach to it).

As mentioned earlier there is another type of solution which involves using promises. There are a bunch of libraries that you can use and actually Mongoose returns a promise from the `exec` method. However if you are on Node 0.12.x you can also use the native Promise (it was introduced in 0.11 but you should be using 0.12.x over 0.11.x). A benefit to using the native promise over the one returned from Mongoose is that you can execute these requests in parallel since they don't depend on each other.

```
site.route('/campus/development')
  .get(function(req, res) {
      Promise.all([
        development.find().exec(), // returns a promise
        jobs.find().exec() // returns a promise
      ]).then(function(results) {
        // results is [devDocs, jobs]
        console.log(results);

        res.send(results);
      }).catch(function(err) {
        res.send(err);
      });
  });
```